# Is there a way to copy the folder according to the changes in the day through PHP?

Tags: php, backup, directory

Here I wanted to take the backup of my folder by using `PHP`

I am having the folder structure as follows:

```
ragu
  |__Raji
      |__ Ranjith
```

If i am going to take the backup on today means the whole folder will come as a backup folder with name of todays date

If **`Next Day`** I am going to take the backup means I should get only the folders which are having the **`changes made on that day`**......

Answer (score 0):

When you write backup files, make sure the file last modified time is set to the same as the original copy.

On the next day you just loop though all files and compare the date of your backup with the current file. If the last modified time is not equal, that means the file is changed and you make the backup again.

The function to read the last modified time is here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filectime.php